# Format string in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm building a string in oracle, where I get a number from a column and make it a 12 digit number with the LPad function, so the length of it is 12 now.
Example: `LPad(nProjectNr,12,'0')` and I get 000123856812 (for example).
Now I want to split this string in parts of 3 digit with a "\" as prefix, so that the result will look like this \000\123\856\812.

How can I archive this in a select statement, what function can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming strings of 12 digits, [`regexp_replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/REGEXP_REPLACE.htm#SQLRF06302) could be a way:

```
select regexp_replace('000123856812', '(.{3})', '\\\1') from dual
```

The regexp matches sequences of 3 characters and adds a `\` as a prefix

Comment: how I did it was like this: `regexp_replace(LPAD(nProjectNr,12,'0'),'(.{3})', '\\\1')`

Answer (score 3):

It is much easier to do this using `TO_CHAR(number)` with the proper format model. Suppose we use `\` as the thousands separator.... (alas we can't start a format model with a thousands separator - not allowed in `TO_CHAR` - so we still need to concatenate a `\` to the left):

**See also edit below**

```
select 123856812 as n,
       '\' || to_char(123856812, 'FM000G000G000G000', 'nls_numeric_characters=.\') as str
from   dual
;

        N  STR
---------  ----------------
123856812  \000\123\856\812
```

Without the `FM` format model modifier, `TO_CHAR` will add a leading space (placeholder for the sign, plus or minus). `FM` means "shortest possible string representation consistent with the model provided" - that is, in this case, no leading space.

**Edit** - it just crossed my mind that we can exploit `TO_CHAR()` even further and not need to concatenate the first `\`. The thousands separator, `G`, may not be the first character of the string, but the currency symbol, placeholder `L`, can!

```
select 123856812 as n,
       to_char(123856812, 'FML000G000G000G000', 
                          'nls_numeric_characters=.\, nls_currency=\') as str
from   dual
;
```

Answer (score 1):

[SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions196.htm#SQLRF06114) returns a substring of a string passed as the first argument. You can specify where the substring starts and how many characters it should be.

Try

```
SELECT '\'||SUBSTR('000123856812', 1,3)||'\'||SUBSTR('000123856812', 4,3)||'\'||SUBSTR('000123856812', 7,3)||'\'||SUBSTR('000123856812', 10,3) FROM dual;
```

Comment: I was thinking the same solution but I wanted something shorter. The other answer was more what I was looking for. Thank you